# How to make td full height of row? Angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I'm using ng-repeat to create a table with schedule blocks, but some are smaller than tr height, and I need that all of them have the same heigh. In each td I have a modified md-checkbox:
[Missing space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy3Ly.png)

I'v created a codepen:
[Schedule](http://codepen.io/andreschica/pen/VpoPqy)

```
 <div id="main" ng-app="MyApp" layout>
  <div ng-view layout="column" flex></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">

<md-toolbar  class="" layout="row">   
  <center>toolbar</center>
</md-toolbar>

  <md-content class="content" >
    <table class="vistaTabla" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr  ng-repeat="hora in bloques[0]">
        <td class="vistaBloque" ng-repeat="bloque in hora">
          <md-checkbox class=" text-longshadow md-whiteframe-1dp bloque dotted" >
            {{bloque.materia}}  {{bloque.nombre}}</td>
          </md-checkbox>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </md-content>

  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: In your css, you don't need these lines,  .tr{display:table-row;  } .td{display:table-cell; } also display:table

Comment: Problem is only about your css, I believe you should focus on it

Comment: Ozgur My css is from my local project, it has properties that I do not use in this schedule, but any way, I already updated my css.
I ask because I've modified my css code and I do not find where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem is the block that is inside `<td>`. 
`<td>` elements are always the size of their `<tr>` parents. The `md-checkbox` element is the one that is messing with you.

Define rule for element `.md-whiteframe-1dp`:

```
.md-whiteframe-1dp {
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you are a genius

Comment: Glad it helped.